# How does the tilde expansion work within a shell variable?

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, tilde

I came across something funny when testing my script.

I can ls my directory from the shell manually if I run

```
$ ls ~/db_backups/
test1  test2
$
```

However, if I assign a shell variable a dir location as such with the tilde, it doesn't work.  I tried this with both single and double quotes.

```
$ backupfolder='~/db_backups'
$ echo $backupfolder
~/db_backups
$ ls $backupfolder
ls: cannot access '~/db_backups': No such file or directory
$
```

What is happening with the tilde substitution inside the shell variable?  Why can't I ls the directory thru the variable like I can manually with the tilde in the dir name?

Comment: Related: [Does ~ always equal $HOME](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/146697) and [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bash` shell will not expand `~` when the tilde is part of the result of a variable expansion.  The unquoted tilde prefix (`~`, `~+` or `~username` for the current user named `username`) is only expanded to the current user's home directory when it is at the start of a word or immediately following a `=` or `:`, optionally followed by `/` and other path elements.

In your case, it would be easier to do the expansion when assigning to your variable `backupfolder`.  This would happen if you left the tilde *unquoted* (using neither single nor double quotes):

```bash
backupfolder=~/db_backups
ls "$backupfolder"
```

... or if you used `$HOME` instead (without single quotes):

```bash
backupfolder=$HOME/db_backups
ls "$backupfolder"
```

In both these assignments, the shell would expand the value to the right of the assignment operator to a pathname of something called `db_backups` in the current user's home directory.

In general, it's often easier to work with `$HOME` in scripts and leave the use of `~` to interactive sessions where it may serve as a handy shortcut.  The `HOME` variable always behaves as a *variable*.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you need both a explicit and unquoted `~user/` (or `~/`) and that can not be the result of a variable expansion.

You need `backupfolder=~/'db_backups'` to have a successful `ls $backupfolder`

#### The long description

The only way that a Tilde expansion might occur is by having an actual **unquoted** `~` up to an also **unquoted** `/`, or the end of the string.

An `echo ~cris/'one space'` will have the tilde (and the username) expanded, but if there is no actual `~` there will be no tilde expansion. It is interesting that such command needs to be quoted as the path contains one space in the `one space` value.

Furthermore, if any of the expansions in this list (expanded after brace expansion in bash): **tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution** is executed (done in a left-to-right fashion), none of the others in the list will be re-applied to the same word (all happen at the same time, kind of).

The brace expansion (first expansion to occur) could then be additionally expanded by the list, and (the two last expansions) word splitting, and path name expansion are applied to the results of the previous steps. For example, this will expand three variables:

```bash
$ echo $HIST{FILE,FILESIZE,SIZE}
/home/cris/.bash_history 2000 1000
```

The results of the brace expansion were re-expanded with variable expansion. But a variable expansion will not be re-expanded with another expansion:

```bash
$ b='$((2+2))'; echo $b
$((2+2))
```

In short, you need both a explicit and unquoted `~user/` (or `~/`) and that can not be the result of a variable expansion.

Please note that an arithmetic expansion is outside this "one expansion only" rule. Inside an arithmetic expansion, the expansions could be recursive several steps deep. For example:

```
$ a=b; b=c; c=d; d=23; echo $(($a))
23
```

And note that I not listed the `process substitution` but it should be added as well.